# How do I Programmatically set ContentTemplate of ContentControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

Can someone translate this to C# code:

```
    <ContentControl Name="test" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myA}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate) FindResource("myA");
```